# Server? Android mobile application which displays data (text, images) from our web portal on our mobile app

Tags: php, android, asp.net, wordpress

I am developing an android app (in progress) which displays txt details (captions and user details) and images. user can upload and view the data on the app.. now when it comes to web site (essential part for project pictures should be uploaded to the portal and can also be uploaded and retrieved from mobile app) i dont know how to start and which platform to choose.

guide needed for web portal development platform and server side. compatibility issues etc. and how can i connect my app with the server/web for updates from the portal.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use a framework like CakePHP which allows me to easily create a xml/json api which the app could interface with.

Comment: thnx.. beside cake php can we use asp.net?